# All SDK platforms not showing

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, platform-sdk

After Installing Android studio I found that only Android 10.0 was just there in the list and nothing else . How do I bring all the platforms ?

Comment: Can you provide some more information on your question: Which version of Android Studio have you downloaded?  Screenshots of what you see.  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add SDK platforms in Android Studio with the SDK Manager.  From the Android Studio menu, select Tools > SDK Manager.  You can select which platforms you want to download from the list, then hit Apply and the selected platforms will be downloaded.

Comment: Iam not getting the list of platforms. I just have a Android 10.0 installed and I see nothing else there.

Comment: Under the SDK Manager select the SDK Update Sites tab to see if the different repos are listed.  The main repo URL is: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository2-1.xml

Comment: when I hover that link it shows "IO exception while downloading manifest".
pls help it is not showing platform 30 (only showing installed platforms)